# count distinct number of records in sql

Tags: query

I have table that contain one is event Id ,second is school Id and third is game ID I want to count number of school who has participated in that event with unique game ID (One school can participate in multiple event with different game)

Example

```
Event Id   school ID   Game ID  
1          20          1  
3          21          2  
1          22          3         
2          22          4  
3          21          5  
1          20          6
```

I need the output is

```
Event Id        schoolCount  
1               2   
3               1  
2               1
```

Comment: Read this.  https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example

Comment: What RDBMS (and version) are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle, etc?

Comment: all game ids are unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a simple and standardized `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a,b,c)
AS VALUES 
    ( 1, 20, 1 ),
    ( 3, 21, 2 ),
    ( 1, 22, 3 ),    
    ( 2, 22, 4 ),
    ( 3, 21, 5 ),
    ( 1, 20, 6 );

SELECT a, COUNT(DISTINCT b)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a;
```

Comment: As i read the user wants to count if a school hit a event more than one time, if the game is not the same,.... But maybe i am wrong, i will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand.

You want to count how many schools participate from a event, including if the same school participates from the same event, but to do not count the same school if the game is the same...

```
dba=# select * from events;
 event_id | school_id | game_id 
----------+-----------+---------
        1 |        20 |       1         
        3 |        21 |       2        
        1 |        22 |       3
        2 |        22 |       4
        3 |        21 |       5
        1 |        20 |       6
        2 |        20 |       1
        5 |        20 |       1
        1 |        20 |       9
        1 |        20 |       9     ->do not count that one
```

Then you want to get:

```
select event_id, count(school_id) 
 from ( select event_id, count(school_id) as school_id 
        from events group by event_id,game_id ) 
 as q 
group by event_id;
 event_id | count 
----------+-------
        1 |     4
        5 |     1
        3 |     2
        2 |     2
```

Am i right? Please if it is right select as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a simple usage of GROUP BY caluse, use this following it works

SELECT event_id, count(school_id) as school_id 
FROM tempTable
GROUP BY event_id;

if u didn't get, please feel free to ask again!